# HorizontalPager in LazyColumn. Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, horizontal-pager

The problem is that the pager is inside LazyColumn, and inside the pager is the list. When changing pages, if the dimensions of one do not match the other, then a white screen is visible for a long time.

```js
fun CustomTabRow(
    tabs: List<Pair<String, @Composable () -> Unit>>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    spaceBetweenTabAndPager: Dp = 0.dp,
    isBeyondBoundsPageCount: Boolean = true,
    horizontalSpaceBetweenContent: Dp = 0.dp,
    selectedTabIndex: Int = 0,
    maxLinesInTitle: Int = 1
) {
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(
        initialPage = selectedTabIndex,
        initialPageOffsetFraction = 0f,
    ) {
        tabs.size
    }
    val dimensions = LocalDimensions.current
    val indicatorHeight = 3.dp
    pagerState.currentPageOffsetFraction

    Column(modifier = modifier) {
        TabRow(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = horizontalSpaceBetweenContent),
            selectedTabIndex = pagerState.currentPage,
            indicator = { tabPositions ->
                TabRowDefaults.SecondaryIndicator(
                    color = PrimaryMain,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .tabIndicatorOffset(tabPositions[pagerState.currentPage])
                        .height(indicatorHeight)
                        .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = dimensions.pagerIndicatorCornerRadius))
                )
            }
        ) {
            tabs.forEachIndexed { index, tabItem ->
                Tab(
                    modifier = Modifier.background(color = BackgroundBase),
                    selected = pagerState.currentPage == index,
                    onClick = {
                        scope.launch {
                            pagerState.animateScrollToPage(index)
                        }
                    },
                    selectedContentColor = PrimaryMain,
                    unselectedContentColor = SecondaryText,
                    text = {
                        Text(
                            text = tabItem.first,
                            style = BoldMontserrat16,
                            maxLines = maxLinesInTitle
                        )
                    }
                )
            }
        }
        HorizontalPager(
            state = pagerState,
            beyondBoundsPageCount = if (isBeyondBoundsPageCount) tabs.size else 0,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top
        ) { index ->
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(horizontal = horizontalSpaceBetweenContent)
                    .padding(top = spaceBetweenTabAndPager)
            ) {
                tabs[index].second()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```js
class TimeTrackingScreen : TimeTracking {

    @OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
    @Composable
    override fun Content() {
        val dimensions = LocalDimensions.current
        val navigator = LocalNavigator.currentOrThrow
        val snackbarHostState = LocalSnackbarHostState.current
        val horizontalPadding = Modifier.padding(horizontal = dimensions.horizontalMedium)

        val screenModel = getScreenModel<TimeTrackingScreenModel>()
        val screenState by screenModel.state.collectAsState()
        val state by screenModel.timeTrackingState.collectAsState()
        val loginScreen = rememberScreen(SharedScreen.LoginScreen)

        when (screenState) {
            is TimeTrackingScreenModel.State.EditLeavingDetailsDialog -> {
                EditLeavingHoursDialog(
                    leavingDetails =
                    (screenState as TimeTrackingScreenModel.State.EditLeavingDetailsDialog)
                        .selectedLeavingDetails,
                    rateMultiplier = state.rate,
                    onSaveHoursClick = rememberSafe { leavingDetails ->
                        screenModel.changeLeavingDetail(leavingDetails = leavingDetails)
                    },
                    onDismiss = rememberSafe { ->
                        screenModel.clearErrors()
                    }
                )
            }

            is TimeTrackingScreenModel.State.EditProjectDetailsDialog -> {
                EditProjectHoursDialog(
                    projectDetails =
                    (screenState as TimeTrackingScreenModel.State.EditProjectDetailsDialog)
                        .selectedProjectDetails,
                    onSaveHoursClick = rememberSafe { projectDetails ->
                        screenModel.changeProjectDetail(projectDetails = projectDetails)
                    },
                    onDismiss = rememberSafe { ->
                        screenModel.clearErrors()
                    }
                )
            }

            else -> { /* Do nothing */ }
        }

        LaunchedEffect(screenState) {
            when (screenState) {
                is TimeTrackingScreenModel.State.Error -> {
                    (screenState as TimeTrackingScreenModel.State.Error).message?.also { message ->
                        snackbarHostState.showMessage(message = message)
                        screenModel.clearErrors()
                    }
                }

                is TimeTrackingScreenModel.State.CriticalError -> {
                    (screenState as TimeTrackingScreenModel.State.CriticalError).message?.also { message ->
                        snackbarHostState.showMessage(message = message)
                        screenModel.clearErrors()
                    }

                    navigator.replaceAll(loginScreen)
                }

                else -> { /* Do nothing */
                }
            }
        }
        Localization(locale = DateUtils.DEFAULT_LOCALE) {
            val localization = Vocabulary.localization

            if (screenState is TimeTrackingScreenModel.State.Delete) {
                DeletionDialog(
                    title = localization.removalOfAbsenceStr(),
                    description = localization.descriptionOfRemovalStr(),
                    positiveButtonText = localization.deleteStr(),
                    negativeButtonText = localization.canselStr(),
                    state = screenState,
                    dimensions = dimensions,
                    onNegativeButtonClick = {
                        screenModel.clearErrors()
                    },
                    onPositiveButtonClick = rememberSafe { ->
                        screenModel.removeLeavingDetail(
                            (screenState as TimeTrackingScreenModel.State.Delete).leavingDetails
                        )
                    }
                )
            }
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .background(color = BackgroundBase)
            ) {
                item(key = TimeTrackingScreenItems.HEADER) {
                    Row(
                        modifier = horizontalPadding.padding(top = dimensions.verticalMedium),
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            text = localization.timeTrackingStr(),
                            style = BoldMontserrat22.copy(color = BlackDefaultText)
                        )
                        BetaDie(modifier = Modifier.padding(dimensions.horizontalSmall))
                    }
                    SpacerHeight(height = dimensions.verticalMedium)
                }

                item(key = TimeTrackingScreenItems.ENTER_HOURS) {
                    Text(
                        modifier = horizontalPadding,
                        text = localization.enterHoursStr(),
                        style = SemiBoldMontserrat22
                    )
                    SpacerHeight(height = dimensions.verticalSmall)
                }

                item(key = TimeTrackingScreenItems.ENTERING_AND_MISSING_HOURS_CONTENT) {
                    CustomTabRowWithEnteringAndMissingHoursContent(
                        projectList = state.projectDetails,
                        currentMonth = state.currentMonth,
                        typesAbsence = listOf(
                            LeaveType.SickLeave,
                            LeaveType.Idle,
                            LeaveType.Training,
                            LeaveType.Vacation
                        ),
                        state = screenState,
                        localization = localization,
                        onSaveEnteringHoursSpentOnWork = rememberSafe { projectDetails ->
                            screenModel.saveProjectDetails(
                                projectDetails = projectDetails
                            )
                        },
                        onSaveMissingHours = rememberSafe { leavingDetails ->
                            screenModel.saveLeavingDetails(
                                leavingDetails = leavingDetails
                            )
                        },
                        onMonthChange = rememberSafe { selectedMonth ->
                            screenModel.changeHoursContext(selectedMonth, state.currentYear)
                        },
                        rateMultiplier = state.rate
                    )
                    SpacerHeight(height = dimensions.verticalXXlarge)
                }

                item(key = TimeTrackingScreenItems.MONTH_YEAR_FOR_HOURS_SPENT) {
                    MonthYearForHoursSpent(
                        modifier = horizontalPadding.animateItemPlacement(),
                        text = localization.hoursForStr(),
                        onClick = rememberSafe { monthId, year ->
                            screenModel.changeHoursContext(monthId = monthId, year = year)
                        },
                        currentYearId = state.currentYear,
                        currentMonthId = state.currentMonth
                    )
                    SpacerHeight(height = dimensions.verticalLarge)
                }

                item(key = TimeTrackingScreenItems.CIRCULAR_DIAGRAM) {
                    CustomCircularDiagram(
                        modifier = horizontalPadding.animateItemPlacement(),
                        projectList = state.projectsForDiagram,
                        onBackClick = rememberSafe { -> screenModel.backPressedDiagram() },
                        onNextClick = rememberSafe { -> screenModel.nextPressedDiagram() },
                        isBackEnabled = state.isBackDiagramEnabled,
                        isNextEnabled = state.isNextDiagramEnabled,
                        totalTime = state.normHours
                    )
                    SpacerHeight(height = dimensions.verticalLarge)
                }

                item(key = TimeTrackingScreenItems.PROJECTS_AND_LEAVING_LIST) {
                    CustomTabRow(
                        spaceBetweenTabAndPager = dimensions.verticalMedium,
                        horizontalSpaceBetweenContent = dimensions.horizontalMedium,
                        isBeyondBoundsPageCount = false,
                        tabs = listOf(
                            localization.hoursForStr() to {
                                ProjectsInfoList(
                                    onIconClick = rememberSafe { selectedProjectDetails ->
                                        screenModel.showEditProjectDetailsDialog(selectedProjectDetails)
                                    },
                                    projectsInfoList = state.projectDetails
                                )
                                SpacerHeight(height = dimensions.verticalLarge)
                            },
                            localization.absenceStr() to {
                                LeavingDetailsList(
                                    leavingDetailsList = state.leavingDetails,
                                    onEditIconClick = rememberSafe { selectedLeavingDetails ->
                                        screenModel.showEditLeavingDetailsDialog(selectedLeavingDetails)
                                    },
                                    onDeleteIconClick = rememberSafe { selectedLeavingDetails ->
                                        screenModel.showDeletionDialog(selectedLeavingDetails)
                                    }
                                )
                                SpacerHeight(height = dimensions.verticalLarge)
                            }
                        )
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun DeletionDialog(
    state: TimeTrackingScreenModel.State,
    title: String,
    dimensions: Dimensions,
    description: String,
    positiveButtonText: String,
    negativeButtonText: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onNegativeButtonClick: () -> Unit,
    onPositiveButtonClick: () -> Unit
) {
    DialogWrapper(
        modifier = modifier.padding(horizontal = dimensions.horizontalMedium),
        showDialog = state is TimeTrackingScreenModel.State.Delete,
        onDismissRequest = { /* Do nothing */ }
    ) {
        WarningDialog(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(dimensions.horizontalMedium),
            title = title,
            description = description,
            isLoading = state is TimeTrackingScreenModel.State.Loading,
            confirmButtonText = positiveButtonText,
            cancelButtonText = negativeButtonText,
            onConfirmButtonClick = onPositiveButtonClick,
            onCanselButtonRequest = onNegativeButtonClick
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun CustomTabRowWithEnteringAndMissingHoursContent(
    onSaveEnteringHoursSpentOnWork: (projectDetails: UiProjectDetails) -> Unit,
    onSaveMissingHours: (leavingDetails: UiLeavingDetails) -> Unit,
    currentMonth: Int,
    state: TimeTrackingScreenModel.State,
    localization: Localization,
    onMonthChange: (selectedMonth: Int) -> Unit,
    projectList: List<UiProjectDetails>,
    typesAbsence: List<LeaveType>,
    rateMultiplier: Double
) {
    val dimensions = LocalDimensions.current

    CustomTabRow(
        spaceBetweenTabAndPager = dimensions.verticalMedium,
        horizontalSpaceBetweenContent = dimensions.horizontalMedium,
        tabs = listOf(
            localization.hoursForStr() to {
                EnteringHoursSpentOnWork(
                    projectList = projectList,
                    onSaveProjectDetails = onSaveEnteringHoursSpentOnWork,
                    onMonthChange = onMonthChange,
                    isLoading = state is TimeTrackingScreenModel.State.Loading,
                    currentMonth = currentMonth
                )
            },
            localization.absenceStr() to {
                MissingHours(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    typesAbsence = typesAbsence,
                    isLoading = state is TimeTrackingScreenModel.State.Loading,
                    onSaveLeavingDetails = onSaveMissingHours,
                    rateMultiplier = rateMultiplier
                )
            }
        ),
        isBeyondBoundsPageCount = false
    )
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXBFd.jpg)

https://www.veed.io/view/85492348-dd0a-4f5b-955b-4e949b31b3bb?panel=share

Comment: You might be showing view when current page is updated in your code. You can change your condition such that you update view when `pager.currentPageOffset` is updated. You can keep conditonal offset on the basis of your requirement

Comment: @MeghLath I didnt get you...(

I have attached the code of CustomTabRow with Horizontal pager and Screen. By the way, the component that is responsible for HorizontalPager with lists is signed by a key with the name TimeTrackingScreenItems.PROJECTS_AND_LEAVING_LIST